# How to fetch the action value from AWS policy document and store it as list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to fetch "Action" values from the AWS policy document.
In some policies, the action values are having a list of values(like Policy 1) and in some policies, the action is having a single value which is a string (like Policy 2).

What I need is:

I want to get the action value from the policy and store it as a list.

(Here, Policy 1 is giving expected output but policy 2 is failing.)

**Policy 1:**

```
document_values:
[{'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Sid': 'VisualEditor0', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': ['iam:CreateInstanceProfile', 'iam:DeleteInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetRole', 'iam:GetInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetPolicy', 'iam:ListGroupPolicies', 'iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed'],'Resource': ['arn:aws:iam::*:policy/*','arn:aws:iam::*:instance-profile/*']}, {'Sid': 'VisualEditor1', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': ['iam:ListPolicies', 'iam:ListRoles', 'iam:ListGroups'],'Resource': '*'}]}]
```

**Output - Policy 1:**

```
['iam:CreateInstanceProfile', 'iam:DeleteInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetRole', 'iam:GetInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetPolicy', 'iam:ListGroupPolicies', 'iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed','iam:ListPolicies', 'iam:ListRoles', 'iam:ListGroups']
```

**Policy 2:**

```
document_values:
[{'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Sid': 'VisualEditor0', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': 'sts:AssumeRole', 'Resource':'*"}]}]
```

**Output-Policy2:**

```
['s', 't', 's', ':', 'A', 's', 's', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'R', 'o', 'l', 'e']
```

**Expected output from policy2:**

```
['sts:AsseumeRole']
```

**Python-Code:**
I'm executing the same code for both the policies.

```
inline_services = [j for i in [i['Action'] for i in document_values[0]['Statement']] for j in i]
print(inline_services)
```

How to fetch the action value from the policy document irrespective of string or list..?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing long list comprehension, you could just create simple function:

```
p1 = [{'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Sid': 'VisualEditor0', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': ['iam:CreateInstanceProfile', 'iam:DeleteInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetRole', 'iam:GetInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetPolicy', 'iam:ListGroupPolicies', 'iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed'],'Resource': ['arn:aws:iam::*:policy/*','arn:aws:iam::*:instance-profile/*']}, {'Sid': 'VisualEditor1', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': ['iam:ListPolicies', 'iam:ListRoles', 'iam:ListGroups'],'Resource': '*'}]}]
p2 = [{'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Sid': 'VisualEditor0', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Action': 'sts:AssumeRole', 'Resource':'*'}]}]
  


def get_actions(policy_doc):
    
    actions_list = []
    
    for i in policy_doc[0]['Statement']:
        actions_list += i['Action'] if isinstance(i['Action'], list) else [i['Action']]
            
    return actions_list


print(get_actions(p1))
print(get_actions(p2))
```

Output:

```
['iam:CreateInstanceProfile', 'iam:DeleteInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetRole', 'iam:GetInstanceProfile', 'iam:GetPolicy', 'iam:ListGroupPolicies', 'iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed', 'iam:ListPolicies', 'iam:ListRoles', 'iam:ListGroups']
['sts:AssumeRole']
```